# Why is Node.js app accessible only from 127.0.0.1/localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was about teaching my friend an intro to node but then 
I wonder why this code from nodejs.org:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

when hosted, it doesn't accessible from public ip (it's still accessible from localhost though)
while this code from express.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

does. Please help me modify the basic code the one from nodejs's homepage so that it become accessible from public ip so I can demonstrate it to my friend in a very basic way. The fresh code generated by express.js worked just fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [`server.listen`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) docs,

> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the
>   hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to
>   any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).

To make it accept connections from all ips (`0.0.0.0`), change it to read like this

```
}).listen(80); // No explicit ip, defaults to all ips 0.0.0.0
console.log('Server running in port 80');
```

Answer (score 4):

127.0.0.1 is an internal address

localhost is the default hostname (local domain) which points to it (see /etc/hosts)

0.0.0.0 is the address you want to use to make it accessible from the outside (thus make it public)

seems like when you do not provide the hostname, node's require('http').createServer().listen() defaults to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost's 127.0.0.1