# Node.js websocket server seems confused about it's ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, websocket, ip

> Note: **I have tested this with firewalls on and off.**
>   This is all remote server to server code (there is no browser).
>    I am using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) on centos7.

I have websocket using a `https.server` on my good website (good.com who's ip is 77.77.777.7) that does `.listen(8000,'good.com')` and successfully allows both good.com's clients and bad.com's clients to connect with `new ws(wss://good.com:8000)`

In my good.com server code I get the ips

```
77.77.777.7 connected
66.66.666.6 connected
```

In good.com's terminal I type

```
netstat ltn

tcp        0      0 77.77.777.7:8001      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

That's expected to happen!

But, then I have my bad behaving website (bad.com who's ip is 66.66.666.6) which has the same code. bad.com does `.listen(8000,'bad.com')` and any clients do`new ws(wss://bad.com:8000)`

In my bad.com server code I get the ips

```
127.0.0.1 connected
```

... while good.com's request to open a websocket to bad.com times out! So In bad.com's terminal I type

```
netstat ltn

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

---

If I force bad.com's listen to be `.listen(8000,'66.66.666.6')`

Then good.com times out while bad.com gets `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`

---

Alternatively if I force bad.com's listen to be `.listen(8000,'0.0.0.0')`

Then good.com times out while bad.com's websocket connects but, In my bad.com server code I get the ips

```
127.0.0.1 connected
```

and bad .coms `netstat ltn` shows

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

---

Lastly if I listen without any ip `.listen(8000)` then good.com's clients timeout but, bad.com's clients connect as ip

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 connected
```

and bad .coms `netstat ltn` shows

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8001                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

---

**What I think might be happening**

Something maybe miss-configured in Apache is telling bad.com 'your name is 127.0.0.1 localhost rather than 66.66.666.6'.

or some sort of node.js settings file(?) is prefering to run apps under localhost rather than the ip.

I don't think this problem is related to: [Why is Node.js app accessible only from 127.0.0.1/localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165010/why-is-node-js-app-accessible-only-from-127-0-0-1-localhost)

But I do think it is related to [Cannot run my Node.Js app with my machine's IP address, but can with localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158856/cannot-run-my-node-js-app-with-my-machines-ip-address-but-can-with-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is `listen(8000,'0.0.0.0')` for both sites! The problem was that POODLE attack was disabled on the good site so the bad site could not connect

In /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

I commented out `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`